# Azure Cosmos DB, Gremlin-API and atomic write-operations

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

We are starting a larger project and have to decide the datastore-technology.
For various reasons, we would like to use Cosmos-DB through the Gremlin-API.
The thing which we are not sure about is how to handle atomic writes. Cosmos' consistency levels (from strong to eventual) are fine for us, but we haven't found a way to have atomic write operations through the Gremlin API. We have already written quite complex Gremlin-queries like creating vertices and edges, navigating edges, deleting edges, using side-effects etc. in one Gremlin-statement. So if parts of the statement go wrong, we have no chance to recover from it. It's not an option to split the statements into several smaller ones because in case of an error, we would have to "rollback" the statements up to the erroneous one.

I have found following question but there is no answer so far: [Azure Cosmos Gremlin API: transactions and efficient graph traversal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65161755/azure-cosmos-gremlin-api-transactions-and-efficient-graph-traversal).

Other sources suggest to write idempotent Gremlin-Statements but due to the mentioned complexity, that's not a valid option for us.